# ionic Android does not gets geolocation

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, ionic-framework

new to ionic, have experience with html,javascript and web services.
I am developing geolocation based app where the app needs to show a users location on a Google Map. 
Google Map is not native, it uses a  to connect to API.

On iOS it works well, once i completed developing app on iOS i needed to create Android version of it. 
So i went to Terminal typed: ionic add android and then ionic build android.

The folder have been created but it does not contains any html/javascript code added.

The geolocation does not shows on the app the console says: Could not get geolocation.

There are 2 questions:

1. Why i cant see the code in Android directory and once i wrote the code in the files and controllers how can i update them in Android Emulator?
2. What can be the issue the geolocation does not works? I guess it might be some security issues?or i need to update something related to Android since it is working fine on iOS.

Let me know which part of the code i need to place here to show you more details.

Following code sends an error, of course the code is edited:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation,$http,$ionicPopup,$ionicHistory, $stateParams,  $timeout, $ionicNavBarDelegate) {

            $scope.init = function(){
   var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

}, function(error){
console.log("Could not get location");


});
```

Comment: What version of ionic are you using? And it would be smart to edit your question with the code that is dealing with geolocation.

Comment: @AndrewGraham-Yooll thanks for your comment. Added the code. Problem is with $cordovaGeolocation. The version is: 1.3.2

Comment: updated ionic, still the same issue. Changed to $cordovaGeolocation. navigator - still the same issue the map does not loads on Android, it even loads on browser but not in Android.